# How do I find the proper 'path' and 'face name' for Windows Uniscribe font linking?

Tags: windows, fonts, putty, regedit

I'm attempting to set the 'Consolas' font as a fallback to 'Inconsolata'.  The procedure [is described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/globalization/mt662331), and consists of editing the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink
```

I've added what I thought was the appropriate Multi-string value:

[image: Registry setting: Multi-String: Inconsolata = consola.ttf,Consolas Regular]

Inconsolata is missing [a few unicode line drawing glyphs and characters commonly used in unix console applications](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/unicode/unidata25.html).  I'm using PuTTY as a console to access these applications.  Before I made the edit these characters would simply fail to show up as seen in the screenshot below:

[image: Putty screenshot showing no glyphs]

After the edit I have some success, the characters are being displayed!  It's not using the characters from 'Consolas' however.  See the screenshot below:

Inconsolas with font linking:
[image: Putty screenshot displaying glyphs]

Consolas:
[image: Putty screenshot displaying glyphs in Consolas]

I took the 'path' and 'font face' strings from Windows 10 font control panel.  Can anyone tell me the correct strings to use?

Comment: In addition I've tried: "consola.ttf,Consolas" and "DejaVuSansMono.ttf,DejaVu Sans Mono".  Still seeing the same "default" glyph characters.

Comment: I also tried: "foo.ttf, bar".  Still falls back and displays the line drawing characters.  Maybe just having an entry is enough to get it to fall back to whatever it's displaying ...